# Get nearest 100 postal code latitude and longitude

Tags: api, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

When searching a Postal code in Google map  ,

I want to get nearest 100 postal area code & latitude and longitude .

```
var postData = {
     'value'   : CF242DE,
  };
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+value+'&sensor=false',
 success: function(msg)
     {
"lat":'+msg.results[0].geometry.location.lat+',
"lng":'+msg.results[0].geometry.location.lng+'
}
```

If using above Api ,

I will get only that postalcode area latitude and longitude .

Is ant way to get nearest 100 postal area latitude and longitude .